# Poets of the 19th century

Tags: legending

```
fun[p_] :=
 Module[{per, bd, dd},
  per = Interpreter["Person"][p];
  bd = DateValue[PersonData[per, "BirthDate"], "Year"];
  dd = DateValue[PersonData[per, "DeathDate"], "Year"];
  Range[bd, dd]]

names = 
 {"Napoleon Bonaparte", "Jane Austen", "Hegel", "Marx", "Gauss", "Madame de Stael", "Lenin"};

res = fun /@ names;
par = Partition[#, 2] & /@ Table[Riffle[res[[n]], n] ~ Join ~ {n}, {n, 1, Length @ res}];

ListLinePlot[par,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 Ticks -> {Range[1750, 1980, 10], Automatic},
 GridLines -> {Range[1750, 1920, 10], None},
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend["Rainbow", names, LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn", LegendMarkerSize -> {{10, 10}}],
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02],
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

How can I align the legend to their lifespan bars?

Comment: I suspect that this is going to be difficult if you use standard legending.  (I might be wrong.)  I would build the legend by hand as a Graphics objects and specify the coordinates to match the plot.  Then the task is to align the legend with the plot, which can be accomplished either by using `Row` and setting the ImageMargin on the top and bottom by hand (to make sure they're the same on the legend and the plot) or I would use a package like SciDraw.  SciDraw is great but takes time to learn.  I do hope someone will post an easier solution though ...

Comment: Lenin was a poet??

Comment: @Jens: '*Ode to a large shotgun*' immediately springs to mind.

Comment: If I were you I'd just put the name of the person on the bar itself.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I thought that was Mao Zedong...

Comment: You missed [Ио́сиф Виссарио́нович Ста́лин](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin)

Comment: Love the title.

Comment: @belisarius. Don't think Joe Stalin qualifies. His poetic work was confined to the 20th century.

Comment: @m_goldberg His work was atemporal

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Use the individual legends as tick labels**:

```
dates = Through[{First, Last}@#] & /@ res
```

> {{1769, 1821}, {1775, 1817}, {1770, 1831}, {1818, 1883}, {1777, 1855}, {1766, 1817}, {1870, 1924}}

```
llpd = MapIndexed[Thread@{#, First@#2} &, dates];

legends = MapIndexed[SwatchLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, 7}}][## & @@ #2]}, {#},
                     LegendMarkerSize -> {{10, 10}}] &, names];

ListLinePlot[llpd, Joined -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None,Thread[{Range[7], legends}]}, {Range[1750, 1930,20], Automatic}},
  GridLines -> {Range[1750, 1920, 10], None},
  AxesOrigin -> {1750, 0}, PlotRange -> {{1750, 1930}, {0, 8}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.05], CapForm["Butt"]], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Label the bars with `names`:**

```
ListPlot[llpd, Joined -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Range[1750, 1930,20], Automatic}},
  GridLines -> {Range[1750, 1920, 10], None},
  Epilog -> (Text[Style[#2, 12, Bold], Mean@#1] & @@@ Transpose[{llpd, names}]),
  AxesOrigin -> {1750, 0}, PlotRange -> {{1750, 1930}, {0, 8}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.05], CapForm["Butt"]], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Use the option [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html)**

In versions 10.4+, we can also use the option  [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html):

```
ListLinePlot[llpd, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLabels -> legends, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Range[1750, 1920, 10], None}, AxesOrigin -> {1750, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1750, 1930}, {0, 8}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.05], CapForm["Butt"]], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

To remove the callout curves, use

```
% /. _BSplineCurve -> {}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the two excellent solutions :)

Comment: @eldo my pleasure.. and thank you indeed for a great question.

Answer (score 11):

Borrowing from kguler the legends

```
    legends = 
 MapIndexed[
  SwatchLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, 7}}][## & @@ #2]}, {#}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{10, 10}}] &, names]; 
p1 = 
 ListLinePlot[par, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Ticks -> {Range[1750, 1980, 10], Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{5, 50}, {0, 1}}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[1750, 1920, 10], None}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], ImageSize -> 600];
 p2 = 
 Graphics[Inset[
     legends[[#]], {1940 + StringLength[names[[#]]], #}] & /@ 
   Range[7]]; Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]