# How to create Gantt charts

Tags: plotting, charts

How can one best create standard [Gantt charts](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/Gantt-chart) in *Mathematica*, where the horizontal axis is time (preferably in the *Mathematica* time format) and where one can include labels within each horizontal bar?  `TimelinePlot` and standard `BarChart` and their relatives, which I've tried, are far too kludgy for this.

Comment: There is a specific example in the `BarChart` documentation showing you how to build a Gantt chart of employee's holidays, but I agree that there's definitely some faff involved...

Comment: related: [Poets of the 19th century](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64101/125) -- also related: [Timeline plotting: horizontal bars of time intervals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58604/125)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some idea of the data you're looking to place on this chart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the data `schedule` from @Edmund's answer, (1) wrapping each date range with `Labeled` and (2) modifying `FrameTicks` to add additional labels:

```
ranges = Map[Interval@{First@#, DatePlus @@ #} &, schedule, {2}];
boxlabels = Style[ToUpperCase@#, 12] & /@ RandomWord["Noun", Length[Join @@ schedule]];
labeling = Thread[Join @@ ranges -> boxlabels];
labeledData = Labeled[##, Before]& @@@ # & /@ (Transpose[{#, # /. labeling}] & /@ ranges);
grouplabels = StringTemplate@"GROUP `1`" /@ Range[Length@schedule];
groupsizes = Length /@ ranges;
ticklabels = StringTemplate@"PROJECT `1`" /@ Range[Length[Join @@ schedule]];
spacings = 4;

tlp = TimelinePlot[labeledData, ImageSize -> 700, LabelStyle -> 14, 
    Spacings -> spacings, Frame -> True, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[.25], Automatic}, {Scaled[.02], Scaled[.05]}}, 
    PlotLayout -> "Stacked", 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.03], CapForm[None]], 
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[grouplabels],
    GridLines -> {{AbsoluteTime@{2018, 2, 15, 8}}, None}, 
    Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}] /. Point[__] :> Nothing ;

Show[tlp, Options[tlp[[1]], FrameTicks] /. 
   {None, None} -> {MapIndexed[{ spacings #2[[1]], #} &, ticklabels], 
    MapIndexed[{spacings (Accumulate[groupsizes][[#2[[1]]]] - 
          Floor[groupsizes[[#2[[1]]]]/2]), #} &, grouplabels]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is the trick for the `FrameTicks` for this plot. Would be good if the option worked directly in the plot ; `FrameTicks->{{custom, custom}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`. I tried that and it did not work. (+1)

Comment: Thank you @Edmund. I couldn't get `FrameTicks` work in `TimelinePlot` either.  Also it would have been great if `PlotLabels` had worked with `TimelinePlot`.

Comment: The WFR function [`ProjectDataGanttChart`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ProjectDataGanttChart) started with the code in this answer.

Answer (score 15):

You may use [`TimelinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html) with the [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) option.

For a project with `schedule` of start date and duration for a few teams.

```
SeedRandom[23032]
schedule =
 Partition[
  Transpose@{
    RandomSample[
     DateRange[DateObject@{2018, 2, 1}, DateObject@{2018, 2, 28}, "Day"], 12],
    RandomInteger[{2, 7}, 12]
    },
  3]
```

Then

```
TimelinePlot[Map[Interval@{First@#, DatePlus @@ #} &, schedule, {2}],
 PlotStyle -> Thickness@Scaled@.025,
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, StringTemplate@"Team `1`" /@ Range@4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Additional formatting can be added by referring to the documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Almost what I need.   I would like to 1) label each individual bar (not just all red bars, or all green bars with a legend), and (as with all Gantt charts) label along the left side general topics such as "Project 1", "Project 2" and so on.  NOT a legend.  (It is sort of surprising that *Mathematica* does not have a Gantt chart function, since it is so widely used.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You can use `PlotLayout -> "Stacked"` and `Frame -> All`.  Then `Epilog` some frame labels on labels on it. I tried `FrameTicks` but it does not seem to like it.

Comment: I can't seem to get your comment ideas to work, especially if the labels have different length so that mutual alignment is extremely difficult.  If you could craft a single, minimal example that had all those features, I'd be grateful (and accept your solution).

Answer (score 8):

We can use Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) function [`ProjectDataGanttChart`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ProjectDataGanttChart).

Here is an example:

```
SeedRandom[99];
dsProj = 
 ResourceFunction[“RandomTabularDataset"][
  {10, {"Group", "Project", "StartDate", "EndDate"}}, 
  "Generators" -> {
     ResourceFunction["RandomPetName"][3], 
     RandomWord[6], 
     Table[ResourceFunction["RandomDate"][], #] &, 
     Table[ResourceFunction["RandomDate"][], #] &}]

ResourceFunction["ProjectDataGanttChart"][dsProj]
```

[image]

(Hovering with the mouse on the project bars shows start-and-end-times tooltips.)