# Why do GridLines/Ticks in TimelinePlot not make sense in some cases and what to do about it?

Tags: plotting, ticks, charts, grid-lines

**Fixed in `13.0`**

### Background

Following up on how [`TimelinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html) can be used to plot [GanttCharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) [(176012)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176012/764) I noted some peculiarities with the way `TimelinePlot` automatically draws Ticks and Gridlines.

### Minimum Examples

Here are two simple examples that demonstrate, that Ticks and Gridlines are dependent on the length of some labels.

Now let's plot a simple project schedule using `TimelinePlot`:

```
$schedule1 = {
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2020, 10, 1}], DateObject[{2021, 10, 1}]}], "Step 1", Bottom], 
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2021, 4, 1}], DateObject[{2022, 4, 1}]}], "Step 2", Bottom],
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2022, 4, 1}], DateObject[{2023, 4, 1}]}], "Step 3", Bottom],
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2023, 4, 1}], DateObject[{2023, 10, 1}]}], "Step 4", Bottom]
};

$chart1 = TimelinePlot[ $schedule1,
    AxesOrigin -> Top,
    GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
    PlotLayout -> "Stacked",
    DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}
]
```

[image: Gantt Chart1]

That looks reasonable enough: The gridlines separate the years and the ticks are drawn every two months.

Let's now plot the same schedule, but now we rename *Step 4* to the longer *Implementation*:

```
$schedule2 = {
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2020, 10, 1}], DateObject[{2021, 10, 1}]}], "Step 1", Bottom], 
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2021, 4, 1}], DateObject[{2022, 4, 1}]}], "Step 2", Bottom],
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2022, 4, 1}], DateObject[{2023, 4, 1}]}], "Step 3", Bottom],
    Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2023, 4, 1}], DateObject[{2023, 10, 1}]}], "Implementation", Bottom]
}; 

$chart2 = TimelinePlot[ $schedule2,
    AxesOrigin -> Top,
    GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
    PlotLayout -> "Stacked",
    DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}
]
```

[image: Gantt Chart2]

This does not look right or at least not nice. Note, that using the following explicit sepcification for `GridLines` will give the exact same result:

```
GridLines -> {DateRange[{2021, 1, 1}, {2024, 1, 1}, Quantity[12, "Months"]], None}
```

So, in `$chart2` the month *January* obviously extends from the small tick to the left to the small tick to the right of any label `Jan 2x`, but the gridlines that are supposed to mark the first day of each January sit right in the middle of that month.

**Is this a bug? And what can be done about this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just received an answer from Wolfram's Technical Support, which suggest a workaround around the issue at hand.

Adding an explicit `PlotRange` will fix the issue with the minor ticks:

```
$chart2WithPlotRange = TimeLinePlot[ $schedule2,
    AxesOrigin -> Top,
    GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
    PlotLayout -> "Stacked",
    DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"},
    PlotRange -> {"October 1, 2020", "October 1, 2023"}
]
```

[image: Gantt Chartt with workaround]