# Gantt Chart like rectangles with log scale

Tags: plotting, charts

I need to plot something that looks like a gant chart, but are actual data ranges. These ranges need to be on a log scale. Graphics does not offer a Scalingfunction. A LogPlot with ErrorBars does not work either and would not look ideal. Is it possible to draw rectangles with one axis being log scale?

E.g.:
Min and Max values of the rectangles are the known data.

[image]

Comment: Can you point to an example (even a non-*Mathematica* example)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
dates = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{10, 1000}, {5, 2}];
data = MapIndexed[Thread@{#, #2[[1]]} &, dates];
labels = CharacterRange["A", "E"];
data2 = MapIndexed[Labeled[{#, #2[[1]]}, Style[labels[[#2[[1]]]], White,
  FontSize -> Scaled[.03]], Center] &, GeometricMean /@ dates];
```

#### [`ListLogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLinearPlot.html)

```
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[data,  
  BaseStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[36], CapForm["Butt"]],  
  Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 6}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{50, 100, 200, 500, 1000}, Automatic}}],
 ListLogLinearPlot[data2, PlotMarkers -> ""]]
```

[image]

#### ListLinePlot + [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html)

```
ListLinePlot[data,  BaseStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[36], CapForm["Butt"]], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Linear"}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{50, 100, 200, 500, 1000}, Automatic}}, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[labels[[#2[[1]]]], White, 
    FontSize -> Scaled[.03]], {#, #2[[1]]}, Center] &, Log[GeometricMean /@ dates]]]
```

[image]

#### [`TimeLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeLinePlot.html)

```
TimelinePlot[{Labeled[#, Style[#2, White,  FontSize -> Scaled[.03]], Center]} & @@@ 
  Transpose[{Interval /@ (Map[N@*Log, dates, {-1}]), labels}], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[40], CapForm["Butt"]], 
 Spacings -> .1, PlotMarkers -> "", Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   {Transpose[{Log@#, #} &@{50, 100, 200, 500}], None}}]
```

[image]

#### [`BarChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html)

```
BarChart[{Style[#[[1]], Directive[EdgeForm[], White]], 
    Labeled[Style[#[[2]], Directive[EdgeForm[], #2]], 
     Style[#3, White, FontSize -> Scaled[.03]], Center]} & @@@ 
  Transpose[{dates, ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@dates], labels}], 
 BarOrigin -> Left, BarSpacing -> {0, .25}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Axes -> False, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .5, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

**Thanks:** @David G. Stork for the `GeometricMean` idea to center the labels.

**See also:** [Poets of the 19th century](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64101/125)

Comment: The only needed improvement:  take the geometric mean of each bar's endpoints to get the "middle" placement of the letter.  `Mean` is simply incorrect.  Try `GeometricMean`.

Comment: Thank you @David! I was struggling with exactly that issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
LogLinearPlot[1, 
 {t, .1, 100},
 PlotStyle -> White,
 Epilog -> {Rectangle[{Log[1], .5}, {Log[50], 1}],
   Red, Rectangle[{Log[30], 1.5}, {Log[80], 2}],
   Text[Style["a", White, 18], {Log[7], .75}],
   Text[Style["b", White, 18], {Log[53], 1.75}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is nice, was wondering how to use `Rectangle[]`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
A = 10^5; B = 5;
rectangle[start_, length_, number_] := 
  RegionPlot[Log10[start] <= x <= Log10[start + length] && 
  number <= y <= number + .75, {x, 0, Log10[A]}, {y, 0, B}, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue, BoundaryStyle -> Blue]; 
Show[
  rectangle[10, 300, 1], rectangle[100, 3000, 2], rectangle[1000, 30000, 3], 
  FrameTicks -> {Transpose@{Range[0,5], 10^Range[0,5]}, Automatic, None, None}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2
]
```

[image]

Comment: Axis-Ticks should not be a problem. I'll check tomorrow. It's now night here.

Comment: Added `FrameTicks[]`.  You are right, not a problem.